# PHP Header Location response as empty

Tags: php, header, location

I have an URL like [this one](http://goophim.com/hash.php?goo1=NUjVND7HNWNp7.7y72jMNTjP7ljcNz72NT7W75N_757tNQji7I7Y7.N.NYjPNDN.jN7R7H7HNDNXNAN3Ns7-NR7ONvN0Nk7BNM7F7JjANb7d7I7.NDNINiNU72N6NA7wNGjj92930a877b0aa0a61b74b92c330456c2f1af160684fa9f8a50a4bef62dcf9251jLjtjLNd7yNj78NQN5jxNcj6NUjpj3NvNFNzNQjW7kNbjojo7FNa7vNfNTNvNwNtjc7.Ny7dNi7.N6NIj7NnNJNtNRNSjw72Nh7d7_NvNq7F7B7_NVNp7ONa7179NINJNfjxjbN.NqN575jC7t&goo2=). 
I'm trying to get location from header, but its not showing location as normal.
Here is my function to get header info.

```
function headerInfo ($service_url) {
    $handle = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => 0, 
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
    ));
    $curl_response = curl_exec($handle);
    return $curl_response;
}
```

Response from PHP:

[image: php header response]

Response when trying from browser (chrome developer tool result):
[image: chrome header response]

Comment: Might simply be invalid parameters or an unknown hash, or PHP/Curl requests being blocked. Have you contacted the service provider?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a valid User-Agent.

Like so:

```
function headerInfo ($service_url) {
    $handle = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => 0, 
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
    ));
    $curl_response = curl_exec($handle);
    return $curl_response;
}
```

You can find a list of valid User-Agents here:

[Valid User-Agents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: I've tried that before, but nothing changes then I was removed it from curl function.

Comment: You might try setting the `NOBODY` to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Might be the server was blocked cURL request, kinda weird.

Comment: Hey no problem, I hope you get it figured out.  Curl can finicky sometimes.  Good luck.. ~Cheers